# Visual Studio Identity Framework UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

My problem is I'm trying to create a 'Role' and add it to a user. It errors out on the reference to the UserManager class as asterisked below

```
 public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
 {
 ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var account = new AccountController();
        account.**UserManager**.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);
 var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
```

And my AccountController as follows

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>(ApplicationUser user, string key);
```

I've also tried

```
 public UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> um = new UserManager<>();
```

And both error out with the former saying:

> The overloaded method has some invalid arguements

And the latter saying:

> Type Expected

I also tried

```
 public UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser,string>();
```

And that gave the error:

> This method does not contain a constructor taking 0 arguments

How do I properly implement/call/use the UserManager Class?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497520(v=vs.108).aspx

UserManager has the following constructor definition

```
  public UserManager(   IUserStore<TUser, TKey> store)
```

so when you initiliaze it you need to have IUserStore instance first as follows

1. Implement IUserStore as you need

   ```
    public class MyUserStore<T> : IUserStore<T> where T: ApplicationUser
            { }
   ```
2. Create an instance of MyUserStore

   ```
   MyUserStore  userStore = new MyUserStore<ApplicationUser>();
   ```
3. Create your user manager as

   ```
    UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> um = new UserManager(userStore);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I implemented your first note in the AccountController before the AccountController. 
Your second step I implemented within the AccountController and it took just fine.
Your third step I implemented under the second step in the AccountController and it errors out when I pass in the 'userStore' object. The error message is "Field initalizer can not reference a non-static field/method/property.

Comment: Dont use static fro the initializer